# SharePoint: Is it possible to use term store in SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, custom-list, term-store

I have a list which is hosted in my SharePoint hosted app and in this list I want to use term store to make a field such as country and city. Is it possible to use term store for SharePoint hosted app?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below link which help to read and write the term store set in sharepoint hosted app
[click here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/03/13/taxonomy-picker-in-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/)

Comment: This answers is a link-only answer (which we normally do not encourage). Besides that, the information in the link is for PROVIDER-hosted apps, not SHAREPOINT-hosted apps